Generic Webhook Trigger call is not finding any matching jobs in Jenkins instance
I have configured a Multibranch Pipeline job with a Jenkinsfile containing a very simple GenericTrigger block:
    triggers {
        GenericTrigger(
            causeString: 'Webhook called',
            genericVariables: [
                [defaultValue: '', key: 'TRIGGER_ACTION', value: '$.action']
            ],
            token: 'some-token'
        )
    }

I've also set up a webhook in the corresponding GitHub repository that calls the correct .../generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=some-token URL, sending it "Pull Request" events.
Lastly, this new Multibranch Pipeline job has run successfully (for the PR in question) via branch indexing, and I've also run it manually, so Jenkins should "know" about it.
However, deliveries to that URL either from the GitHub webhook or manually from a local browser result in a 404 response like this:
{
    "jobs": null,
    "message": "Did not find any jobs with GenericTrigger configured!\nA token was supplied.\n"
}

Note that I've successfully used this technique -- set up earlier this year -- with a different Multibranch Pipeline job (different Jenkinsfile, different repo, different token, but otherwise the equivalent), and it works properly: hitting that webhook URL results in a 200 response and a list of the matching jobs, as expected. So, it is likely not an incompatibility between this plugin and Multibranch Pipeline jobs in general.
Why doesn't this new job work?
